# where is wordpress search pagination

Tags: pagination

**Where is wordpress search pagination?**

I used this in my search page:

```
<?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
```

It returns pagination, but I want to add bootstrap pagination to this, but I can't find it. Where is this and how can I add a class?

Answer (score 1):

The code is in [wp-includes/general-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.3.2/wp-includes/general-template.php).

However there aren't any great options for styling the output: there's a hook for you to [modify the link URL](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/paginate_links/), but nothing else. Your best bet might be to call it in type=array mode

```
$links = pagination_links([ "type" => "array" ]);
```

which will return you an array of strings of links of the form

```
<a class="prev page-numbers" href="/page/1/">&laquo; Previous</a>
<a class="page-numbers" href="/page/1/">1</a>
<span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">2</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="/page/3/">3</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="/page/3/">Next &raquo;</a>
```

which you can then process into [Bootstrap form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/):

1. replace "page-numbers" in the class with "page-link"
2. convert the current page span into a regular link with class="active" too
3. wrap each item with in `<li class="page-item">...</li>`
4. and then wrap the whole thing in `<ul class="pagination>..</ul>`.

However it may be simpler to just copy/paste the function into your own code and change the mark-up it generates, rather than trying to unpack and rewrite mark-up after the fact. You potentially lose any future core updates to the function, but I think those are unlikely beyond occasional aria changes.